# Como instalar a biblioteca Rain TPL?

Tags: php, classes, template, biblioteca

Alguém poderia me mostrar um exemplo? Pois, eu coloquei aqui no meu `index.php` dessa forma, mas, acredito que está defasado. Com a versão atual, acredito que deve ser diferente, porque não funcionou e está dando erro.

```
#Instalando raintpl
include "lib/template/raintpl/rain.tpl.class.php"; //aqui é onde está meu arquivo
raintpl::$tpl_dir= $_GET ['r']."/tpl/"; //aqui o caminho da pasta que ficará o template
raintpl::$cache_dir= $_GET ['r']."/tpm/"; // aqui onde armazenará o cache
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente desta forma:

```
raintpl::configure("base_url", null );
raintpl::configure("tpl_dir", $_GET['r']."/tpl/" );
raintpl::configure("cache_dir", $_GET['r']."/tpm/" );
```

Não faço ideia do que o $_GET['r'] é mas tenta assim.

Comment: no caso você sugere que retire o Include e substitua por a linha: raintpl::configure("base_url", null );

Comment: Não não o include permanece o que substitui é as outras linhas.